# Multiple AngularJS Projects in Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

I'm creating a larger project that will need to be able to grow considerably over time and am having some trouble with AngularJS project structure.  I have found several helpful tutorials about project structure that work very will with a single project but what I would like to do is have several Visual Studio projects and have a "*Shell*" project with an ng-view call the other projects to display within the view.  The structure would look a little like this.

> - Root
>
>   - Shell Project  (*This is the root page with the ng-view loading the other pages*)
>   - Web App 1 Project
>   - Web App 2 Project
>   - Group of Apps Folder
>
>     - Web App 3 Project
>     - Web App 4 Project
>   - Web App 5 Project

Most of the project templates I have seen have a single project and just have a large number of sub folders within the project.  I would prefer to not go with this style because like I stated before this project will grow to a very large size and I would like to keep it as manageable as possible.  Is what I am trying to do possible or is there a better way to setup the project that AngularJS or Visual Studio is designed to use?

Comment: I divide my applications into *modules*. You can see an example here: http://oi59.tinypic.com/2ntfby9.jpg - In case you'd have more *Controllers* and *Services*, I create separate folders for those inside each *module*

Comment: That's similar to how I see most of the projects set up.  I plan on using that structure within each project but ideally I would like to have the different applications in my project in to be within different projects.  So that file structure would be in each of the Web App Projects.

Comment: I'd look at using linked files from each web project to pull in the shell files.